# Property rename with variable in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My goal is to pull the group members of three separate AD groups and pull out the $_.name only while renaming the field in an array to the name of the group itself.  At the end I want to Out-GridView it so some users can see who is in what groups.

Here's what I have at current and for some reason it works but only runs through the first entry in the variable.

```
$groups = "explore","user", "dist"
$report = foreach ($group in $groups)
{Get-ADGroupMember $group | Select @{Name="$group";Expression=
{$_.name}}}
$report | Out-GridView
```

Why is this stopping at the first entry?  What am I missing here?  I also tried to make a $report an array as $report = @() and then put $report += in the loop.  Neither worked.  I feel like i'm missing something really dumb.  Any help is appreciated.

Again at the end i'd love the gridview to pop up showing three columns each with the group name and members below.  Thanks for any help!

Example desired output:

```
explore      user       dist
user1        user4      user6
user2        user3      user7
user4        user7
```

I can do this with one group by just pulling the group members, selecting the name and then dumping it into a name/expression array.

Its doing it for all three in one out-gridview that is proving difficult.

Comment: Interesting it only seems to show the first set of objects that have the same properties. Writing `$report` to the console exhibits similar behavior, I see a bunch of objects with the same `explore` property and then a bunch of blank lines representing the other objects. On the other hand `$report | Format-List *` will print all the objects.

Comment: When I run it I get the output for just one of the entries and it seem to be variable which one of those entries it is.  I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try.

```
$groups = "explore","user", "dist"
$report = foreach($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | % {
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{'Group'=$group; 'User'=$_.name})
    }
}

$report | Out-GridView
```

---

If you need to add additional columns, just add them to the object properties.

---

**EDIT**

I don't think that what you want to do is feasible in a readable manner. The gridview is designed to display data in the same form as a CSV or SQL DB table. You have your columns that denote the objects properties, and rows that denote a single object. The only way to display the data in the form that you want would be to have gaps where one column has data and the other column is blank.

This code is as close as you will get to what you want but it will not display properly in the grid view.

```
$groups = "explore","user", "dist"
$report = New-Object -TypeName psobject

$groups | % {
    $report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value @()
}

foreach($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | % {
        $report.($group) += $_.Name
    }
}

$report
```

Comment: This is close but I was hoping to have three columns, each with a header of the name of the group instead of a column with the groups in it.

Comment: @J235711 Can you provide the output you are looking for as an example?

Comment: @AlexSarafian I guess what I'm looking for, which I'm realizing is hard to produce, is something like what I added to the original message.

Something so that they're able to be sorted with a top click and each column name represents the group that is having its members pulled.